# Adding image links seems to randomly not work?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, images

I asked [Making the YUI TestLogger show only tests that fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182125/) on Stack Overflow, and added an image from my Blogspot account. When I edit the question I can see the image, but in the final question the image is missing, replaced by its alt text only.

Can anyone else see the image? Is it some random [Pebkac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEBKAC) error, a bug in the markdown, or some other hot-linking problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you might be using an image host that is testing the browser's referrer and refusing to render the image if the referrer is not from the same domain.

I moved the image to ImageShack and it's fine.

(the other thing to watch out for here is URLs with *both* - and _ in the filename. The Markdown server-side parser really doesn't like that. Didn't see it here though.)

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the question and just get the broken image icon in all modes - viewing and in the edit preview.

If I paste the link into my browser I can see the image - so that's obviously correct.

You know you can use the `<img src="">` format for images too.

Comment: I guess you meant "img src=..." rather than a/href. I've used Blogger before without problems... I wonder if the _ in the URL threw it?

Comment: @rq - yes indeed - post updated.

Answer (score 1):

No problem seeing the image.

Tested on different browsers (Opera, IE, Chrome), with and without referrer header information. So you might be able to rule out Blogspot not allowing hotlinking.

Comment: Cool, I've edited it now - looks like something was off with the `![]` markdown?